# How do I change raw values into rank orders?

Tags: r

I am in the process of analyzing data and need to convert the raw values into rank orders.  How do I do this in R?   Thank you very much! 
Ju

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your questions will get a better response if you provide example code and explain what you've tried already.  In this case, you probably got downvoted because a quick search for "rank" would have solved things for you, so it looked like you hadn't researched things properly before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your values are in some sort of data structure, have you tried `?rank`?